# Can I obtain a Lightball in X/Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I'm having a very  hard time obtaining a light ball. As far as I know, sometimes Pikachu hold them, at a rate of 5%. If a pokemon with Compound Eyes is in the lead, this jumps to 60%.

- I've caught 38 pokemon using a lead with Static.
- I've caught 4 using a lead with Compound Eyes
- I've Thief'ed 5 with Compound Eyes.

No light ball.
This [Yahoo Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20131019152635AAJvRHl) says it's unobtainable.
However, I've seen folks in GTS with pikachus carrying the light ball.

Any ideas? Is it obtainable?